# How to pass (and after get) array of parameters with Commons CLI?

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I have following code:

```
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt(SOURCES)
                .withDescription("path to sources")
                .hasArg()
                .withArgName("PATHS")
                .create());
...
CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
line = parser.parse(options, args);
...
System.out.println(line.getOptionValues(SOURCES));
```

I invoke application with parameters

```
-sources=path1, path2
```

in result I see `["path1"]`

I want to get both arguments. How can I pass it?

what should I write in command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the argument values space-delimited, rather than comma-delimited:

```
-source=path1 path2
```

Also, you need to use `.hasArgs()` rather than `.hasArg()` to return more than one argument value.  You can also specify `.hasArgs(2)` for an explicit number of argument values.  Here's a working example:

Input: -source=path1 path2

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("sources").withDescription("path to sources").hasArgs().withArgName("PATHS").create());

        CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
        CommandLine line = null;

        try {
            line = parser.parse(options, args, true);
        } catch (ParseException exp) {
            System.err.println("Parsing failed.  Reason: " + exp.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line.getOptionValues("sources")));
    }
}
```

Output: [path1, path2]

Comment: line.getOptionValues(note s)

Comment: I've posted a working example with more explanation.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass an array, you should replace `hasArg()` with `hasArgs()` to indicate that the option may have multiple values. Now you can pass them like this:

```
-sources path1 path2
```

If you want to be able to pass them comma-separated, you can call `withValueSeparator(',')` on your `OptionBuilder`, resulting in code like the following:

```
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt(SOURCES)
    .withDescription("path to sources")
    .hasArgs()
    .withValueSeparator(',')
    .withArgName("PATHS")
    .create());
```

Now you can pass them this way:

```
-sources path1,path2
```

Keep in mind, however, that space will still be treated as a separator.